# Prove that this sequence is an arithmetic progression

Tags: solution-verification, proof-explanation

Let $(a_n)_{n\geq1}$ be a sequence of nonzero real numbers such that $\forall n\in N \geq2$ we have

$\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{a_ja_{j+1}}=\frac{n-1}{a_1a_n}$

Prove that the sequence is an AP.

By direct proof.

$(a_n)_{n\geq1}$ is AP if and only if the recurrence

$a_{k+2}+a_k=2a_{k+1}$  $\forall k\geq1$.

Since $n\ge2$ we show that when $n=3$ we have:

$\sum_{j=1}^{3-1}\frac{1}{a_ja_{j+1}}=\frac{3-1}{a_1a_3}$

$\therefore \frac{1}{a_1a_2}+\frac {1}{a_2a_3}=\frac{2}{a_1a_3}$

Simplifying this further  we get:

$a_3+a_1=2a_2$ which meets the necessary and sufficient condition stated above for an AP when $k=1$.

Hence proof complete.

By Induction Argument.

Carrying indunction on $n$.

$n=2$ we have:

$\sum_{j=1}^{2-1}\frac{1}{a_ja_{j+1}}=\frac{2-1}{a_1a_2}$

$n=k$ we have:
$\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}\frac{1}{a_ja_{j+1}}=\frac{k}{a_1a_{k}}$

By means of substitution we can rewrite the immediate above as:

$\left (\sum_{j=1}^{k}\frac{1}{a_ja_{j+1}}\right)-\frac{1}{a_ {k}a_{k+1}}=\frac{k-1}{a_1a_{k}}$

$\therefore \frac{k}{a_1a_{k+1}}-\frac{1}{a_ {k}a_{k+1}}=\frac{k-1}{a_1a_{k}}$

Leading to :

$\frac{ka_{k}-a_1}{a_{k+1}a_1 a_{k}}=\frac {k-1}{a_1a_{k}}$

$k (a_{k})-a_1=ka_{k+1}-a_{k+1}\mapsto (1) $

$n=k+1$ we have:
$\sum_{j=1}^{k}\frac{1}{a_ja_{j+1}}=\frac{k}{a_1a_{k+1}}$

$n=k+2$ we have:
$\sum_{j=1}^{k+1}\frac{1}{a_ja_{j+1}}=\frac{k+1}{a_1a_{k+2}}$

By means of substitution we can rewrite the immediate above as:

$\left (\sum_{j=1}^{k}\frac{1}{a_ja_{j+1}}\right)+\frac{1}{a_ {k+1}a_{k+2}}=\frac{k+1}{a_1a_{k+2}}$

$\therefore \frac{k}{a_1a_{k+1}}+\frac{1}{a_ {k+1}a_{k+2}}=\frac{k+1}{a_1a_{k+2}}$

Leading to :

$\frac{ka_{a+2}+a_1}{a_{k+1}a_1 a_{k+2}}=\frac {k+1}{a_1a_{k+1}}$

$k (a_{k+2})+a_1=ka_{k+1}+a_{k+1}\mapsto (2) $

Solving the two linear recurrence relations  $(1)$ and $(2)$ we have:

$a_1=ka_k-(k-1)a_{k+1}$.

$a_1=ka_{k+1}+a_{k+1}-k (a_{k+2})$

Multiplying   through the first equation by $-1$  and adding to the second we have :

$0=-ka_k+2ka_{k+1}-k (a_{k+2})$.

$k (a_{k+2})-2ka_{k+1}+ka_k=0$.

Rearranging  and dividing through by k we have:

$a_{k+2}+a_k=2a_{k+1}$.

Hence meeting the necessary and sufficient condition.

Proof complete.

Contributions appreciated!

Comment: Point noted...Thanks  for your comment.

Comment: I don't reach the same conclusion at the end if we do not restrict $k$ (it was supposed to be arbitrary, right?), perhaps it can be modified to look like the intended form?

Comment: I'm not sure about the details, but perhaps this is a double-recurrence scenario, where you created one recurrence with $ka_{k+2}+a_1=(k+1)a_{k+1}$, then you need to work with this recurrence to achieve the desired result...

Comment: "*Letting* $k=1$" $-$ You cannot choose $k$ here, that's the induction variable. Instead, write the relation for two consecutive values then eliminate $a_1$ between them and you'll get a relation between $a_k, a_{k+1}, a_{k+2}\,$.

Comment: No, it would follow that $k\ge 1$ from those two statements.  $k$ remains arbitrary in the iteration step of an induction.

Comment: Indeed .. I see that now...thanks.

Comment: I have reworked the induction argument. I think it should be ok now. Verification most welcomed.Thank you all.

Comment: That looks correct now; I had thought I was getting a slight indexing issue with the $k$ and term numbers, but your reworking seems to not suffer from that problem.

Comment: Note that you may wish to recast your proof without using induction, since you can arrive at the general form without it...

Comment: Indeed...thanks for your input.